# Google drive api v3 permission details

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to receive all permissions fields, but especially permissions details

```
  "permissionDetails": [
    {
      "permissionType": string,
      "role": string,
      "inheritedFrom": string,
      "inherited": boolean
    }
  ]
```

I tried

```
$optpParams = array('fields' => "id,emailAddress,permissionDetails"
);
```

or use *

```
'fields' => "*"
```

I received some data but there were no "permissionDetails".

Comment: Are you using [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) or [Permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) method?

Comment: I received file list $results = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams); And for each file I received permission $request = $perm->permissions->get($pfolderId, $permission, $optpParams);

Comment: As far as I know, the `permissionDetails` field is an output field which is present only for shared drive items. Please be noted that details of whether the permissions on this shared drive item are inherited or directly on this item. Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the permissionDetails it's only present for shared drive items (in case you're using your normal drive) [1].

I’m able to retrieve permissionDetails but only if i also put “teamDrivePermissionDetails“ in the fields (is the same thing). Also if you use the wildcard “*” it will retrieve all the information including permissionDetails. But in the rest of the cases the permissionDetails came empty, so it’s an issue that i'll report to google.

With this code i’m able to retrieve permissionDetails:

```
$optpParams = array('supportsAllDrives' => true, 'fields' => "id,emailAddress,teamDrivePermissionDetails,permissionDetails");
```

Or simply:

```
$optpParams = array('supportsAllDrives' => true, 'fields' => "id,emailAddress,teamDrivePermissionDetails");
```

To obtain all the information including permissionDetails:

```
$optpParams = array('supportsAllDrives' => true, 'fields' => "*");
```

Remember to put the value 'supportsAllDrives' => true in the $optParams array, so the request can find files/folders that belong to a Shared Drive [2].

For future information, they’re deprecating teamDrivePermissionDetails and permissionDetails it’s the replacement (although not working perfectly for now) [1].

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions

[2] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get